# Rails new controller not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

#### When i type in 'rails new controller pages', its not creating a controller for me and gives me this error in command prompt:

*C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\pinteresting>rails generate controller pages C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/va lues/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/rout ing/mapper.rb:229:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (Argum entError)*

## Even after doing "rails generate controller" im still getting an error:

*C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/rout
ing/mapper.rb:229:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (Argum
entError)*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new controller for your application, you use the `rails generate`command. `rails new` is used to create an entire new Rails application.

> $ bin/rails generate controller Usage: rails generate controller NAME
>   [action action] [options]

In your case, you'd use:

```
rails generate controller Pages
```

Please review the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html).

Comment: @JoshuaMinchew I can't help you with whatever error you're getting unless you tell me what it is.

Comment: @JoshuaMinchew Never mind. I see you edited your question to something entirely different. If you have a new question, post it separately rather than editing your original question into something else. By doing what you did, you end up disconnecting questions from answers, making the thread completely unusable for subsequent readers who might run into the same problem you encountered. Remember that Stack Overflow isn't here just for your personal benefit -- your experience can help others.